# Remove Meta author by code snippet in Yoast WordPress SEO

Tags: wordpress, metadata, code-snippets, yoast

Is there a way to remove the metadata 'author' code inserted by Yoast SEO in WordPress?

```
    <meta name="author" content="login.username" />
    <!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
```

I have looked through all the options in the Yoast SEO plugin and tried a few PHP Code Snippets but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Paully

Answer (score 4):

There is a filter `wpseo_meta_author` since version 19.3 you can use to change or remove the content of the author meta tag, so to remove it:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_meta_author', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: it's working. Upvote from my side. Is there any way to remove it from yoast-schema-graph as well/

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the answer you are looking for: https://yoast.com/help/disable-enable-author-archives/

If you disable the author archive this should remove the author from posts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I have disabled the author archive as you suggested, and reindexed the Yoast data, but it has not removed the meta line in the source code.  If the content of the metadata was just "something else" that would be fine, but the fact that Yoast puts in the login name of the WP user is a big no no for me!  Hopefully, someone else will have a nice PHP functions code snippet to do this.  Their official documentation mentions removing description but not author.  Aaarrggh!  :-)

Comment: Ah - look what I found!  https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/18648

Comment: Ah yes, I knew this worked before for me. At least its down to a bug rather than a user mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes up with the same problem with you, I found out recently (December 2023 now!) that if you deactivate Slack feature, all info about author is removed. Check here the instructions to [activate Slack](https://yoast.com/help/enhanced-slack-sharing/) (but you follow them to toggle it off)! Unfortunately this solution depends on your theme also, it's not 100% that it will work...

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your (future) answers. Your answer should be useful without the link. So, when using links, please quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Also, remember to give credit to the author.